# Direct literal string to program as input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch-file to download a file via `psftp` (our computation cluster only allows sftp and ssh). So I am using the `psftp` utility from PuTTY in Windows 7.
The manual solution to this is:

```
C:\>psftp -l loverboy server.com
psftp> get /usr/home/loverboy/myfile.txt
```

With `psftp` I could list the commands in a simple text file and then issue

```
C:\>psftp -l loverboy -b get.txt server.com
```

But I am unsatisfied with this solution as it requires having an auxiliary file with the commands and I want to keep the folder clean and tidy.

In bash, I believe I could have done something ala (assuming same executables):

```
[loverboy@server ~]$ psftp -l loverboy server.com < 'get /usr/home/loverboy/myfile.txt'
```

(of cause, if I were doing it in linux I would have an entire suite of options...)
The corresponding command (`<`) in cmd would however try to read a file and use that as input.

**Question:** Can I send input to a command, without having to write the input to a text file?

Comment: The batch file can create and delete an ftp script file.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at ways to circumvent creating temporary files, i.e. using a literal string as input. For a single get command, this could be more elegant and simple.